# Unserializing data doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

Been at this for the past 5 hours and I'm stumped. Tried the most ridiculous functions to try and fix it but to no avail.

I'm retrieving data from a WP database. The data has, before insert, had 1 array serialized using the `serialize()` function from PHP. It then gets inserted into WP database using the WP function `update_user_meta`. [This function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)'s reference says:

```
$meta_value
(mixed) (required) The new desired value of the meta_key, which must be different from the
existing value. Arrays and objects will be automatically serialized. 
Note that using objects may cause this bug to popup.
    Default: None
```

This made me think data may have been serialized twice. Though going through a whole lot of functions like `unserialize()`, `array_map`, `json_decode`, and combinations of these and more I have now got the below:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($fbData)){

    $someValue = $fbData[$i]['meta_value'];
    $usermeta = array_map( function( $a ){ return $a[0]; }, get_user_meta( $fbData[$i]['user_id'] ));
    if( $usermeta['facebookmeta'] ){
        $unserialized = unserialize( $usermeta['facebookmeta'] );
        //other methods tried: unserialize( unserialize
        // unserialize( json_decode(
        // json_decode( unserialize( json_decode(
        // json_decode( unserialize(
        // unserialize( array_map( 
        // unserialize( array_map( json_decode
        // whole lot others
        var_dump( $unserialized );
    }
$i++;
}
```

However this doesn't work. This goes in with the `$fbData`:

```
'facebookmeta' => string 's:668:"a:16:{s:2:"id";s:9:"123456";s:4:"name";s:12:"Henkie";s:10:"first_name";s:4 //and so on
```

This is the result:

```
string 'a:16:{s:2:"id";s:9:"123456";s:4:"name";s:12:"Henkie";s:10:"first_name";s:4: //and so on
```

As is visible it from the result, it just removes the "`s:668:"`" from the start, which indicates it's a 668 character string and leaves the remainder untouched.

How come the unserialization doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops found the answer! :) WP function hidden in [functions.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L0) from WP themselves.

```
function maybe_unserialize( $original ) {
    if ( is_serialized( $original ) ) // don't attempt to unserialize data that wasn't serialized going in
        return @unserialize( $original );
    return $original;
}
```

Fixed the unserializing by doing:

```
$unserialized = maybe_unserialize( unserialize( $usermeta['facebookmeta'] ));
```

Returns it all in a neat array! :)

Happy happy! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can unserialize twice:

`$unserialized = unserialize( unserialize( $usermeta['facebookmeta'] ) );`

NB: There's no need to serialize when using `update_user_meta`, it serializes automatically for you, cf. `maybe_serialize`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize

Comment: Yes I figured, however unserializing twice gives me nothing in return. Also, working with pre-created data, too late to change that.

Comment: Try to validate the string as JSON at http://jsonlint.com/ and see what it tells you?

Comment: Interesting site ;) But nope, it doesn't recognise it as JSON. Completely open to ideas though, really don't want to recreate 10.000+ records by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with wp_options where custom post types have serialize data.
I've figure that maybe there was a charset issue, and in fact... ta da!
Try this:

```
$unserialized = unserialize( utf8_encode($atest[0]['option_value'] ) );
```

Where $atest[0] is thearray from mysql.
Hope this helps!

Aisfrond

Comment: I found that using WP's own `maybe_unserialize($var)` works better than just using `unserialize()`. As shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16281985/1155833) below, it checks whether or not an array is serialized, otherwise returns the data untouched.