# Reverting serialization returns bool false

Tags: php

I have a database entry via Wordpress that has stored in an array 2 items.

```
// nieuwe query om instructors op te halen

    $instructor = get_meta_values ('apus_educator_instructors','edr_course');   
    $instructorids = unserialize($instructor)   ;                               
    var_dump($instructor);

// check of huidige instructor in array staat
    echo $user->ID;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($instructorids);
    echo "</pre>";                                          

    if(in_array($user->ID, $instructorids)) {

        echo "hoera";
    }
```

When I do a var_dump:

`array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "a:2:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"6";}" }`

but when i try to unserialize it, it returns a bolean false. I dont see an error really in the string when I try to unserialize it.

Comment: Show the code please?

Comment: The given example makes me think you're trying to do `unserialize($var)`, while you should be doing `unserialize($var[0])`.

Comment: I totally agree with M. @Narf

Comment: Based on your edit, @Narf has it exactly right

Comment: Had that some years back, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281985/1155833). In short: `$unserialized = maybe_unserialize($var)`. And indeed @Narf's comment, you've got an array there, so `maybe_unserialize($var[0])`.

Comment: "In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued. " -PHP.net. Obviously there is something wrong with your string or you are passing the wrong variable. var_dump() what you wan't to deserialize to check if it's correct. Edit: All the comments loaded in for me but I can see people were already pointing you towards the correct answer.