# How can I convert the WordPress string meta_key value into simpler array?

Tags: php, wordpress, explode

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

I want to break this down and convert into some sort of array.

Comment: Try to get it by get_user_meta and it will return you an array, and if not use unserielize(), that's all.

Comment: This is the format PHP outputs for data passed to the `serialize()` function. As Dipak said, we can turn it back into an array by passing the value to `unserialize()`. Where did you find this value? Usually, we shouldn't need to manually unserialize values. The platform should provide an API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unserializing data doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281156/unserializing-data-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `maybe_unserialize( 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}' )` function of wordpress for better output. Just pass the serialize string and it will return you an array.

Answer (score 0):

The string below actually represents an array in serialized form.

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

Here:
a:1 means an array with a single element
s:13 means string and the length of the string followed by

```
    Array 
{
     "administrator" => "1"
}
```

in you case

```
 $mydata = a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";};
    $mydata = unserialize($mydata);
    echo $mydata['administrator in'][0];
```

Once that is in the table, you can use the unserialize() function to return it to an array for use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in WordPress functions you shouldn't have to manipulate the data at that level.  Taken from [here](https://kellenmace.com/get-current-users-role-in-wordpress/)

```
/*
 * Get user's role
 *
 * If $user parameter is not provided, returns the current user's role.
 * Only returns the user's first role, even if they have more than one.
 * Returns false on failure.
 *
 * @param  mixed       $user User ID or object.
 * @return string|bool       The User's role, or false on failure.
 */
function km_get_user_role( $user = null ) {
    $user = $user ? new WP_User( $user ) : wp_get_current_user();
    return $user->roles ? $user->roles[0] : false;
}
```